# How to change an event depending on which radio button is selected C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, radio-button

Using a C# program to send data to an Arduino microcontroller for a CNC machine.

String is sent on the click of a button to the Arduino.

Want the code to be different depending on which radio button has been selected.

Current format is:

```
if (radio1.Checked)
{
serialPort1.Write("string1");
}
else if (radio2.Checked)
{
serialPort1.Write("string2");
}
```

Having the string sent on CheckedChanged event is not possible.

Comment: You are using WinForms right? When you want separate events for both radio buttons, would it not be better to use the CheckedChanged event for both radio buttons?

Comment: _"Want the code to be different depending on which radio button has been selected"_ -- and what is wrong with the code you already have? _"Having the string sent on CheckedChanged event is not possible"_ -- I guess not, since you say you want to send the string when a button is clicked. But you can _change_ the string to be sent on that event. There are certainly lots of alternatives to the code you apparently have now, but there's no indication in your question that would help anyone understand which of those alternatives, if any, would actually answer your question.